# Groupby date but filling nulls from different rows and summing numerics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame

```
         date col1 col2 col3  v1  v2  v3
0  2020-01-01    a  NaN  NaN   1   1   1
1  2020-01-01  NaN    b  NaN   1   1   1
2  2020-01-01  NaN  NaN    c   1   1   1
3  2020-01-02    d  NaN  NaN   2   2   2
4  2020-01-02  NaN    e  NaN   2   2   2
5  2020-01-02  NaN  NaN    f   2   2   2
6  2020-01-03    g  NaN  NaN   3   3   3
7  2020-01-03  NaN    h  NaN   3   3   3
8  2020-01-03  NaN  NaN    i   3   3   3
```

I want to group by the date column, sum the v1, v2 and v3 columns, while placing non-null values from the other rows to fill in the NaNs, like below:

```
         date col1 col2 col3  v1  v2  v3
0  2020-01-01    a    b    c   3   3   3
1  2020-01-02    d    e    f   6   6   6
2  2020-01-03    g    h    i   9   9   9
```

sample code was created this way:

```
import pandas a pd
sample = pd.DataFrame([
    {'date':'2020-01-01', 'col1':'a','v1':1,'v2':1,'v3':1},
    {'date':'2020-01-01','col2':'b','v1':1,'v2':1,'v3':1},
    {'date':'2020-01-01','col3':'c','v1':1,'v2':1,'v3':1},
    
    {'date':'2020-01-02','col1':'d','v1':2,'v2':2,'v3':2},
    {'date':'2020-01-02','col2':'e','v1':2,'v2':2,'v3':2},
    {'date':'2020-01-02','col3':'f','v1':2,'v2':2,'v3':2},
    
    {'date':'2020-01-03','col1':'g','v1':3,'v2':3,'v3':3},
    {'date':'2020-01-03','col2':'h','v1':3,'v2':3,'v3':3},
    {'date':'2020-01-03','col3':'i','v1':3,'v2':3,'v3':3},
             ])[['date','col1','col2','col3','v1','v2','v3']]
```

Comment: `df.groupby('date', as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: `df.groupby("date", as_index=False).agg({"col1":"first","col2":"first","col3":"first", "v1":"sum","v2":"sum","v3":"sum"})`?

Comment: @ Henry Yik, that actually did it! Thanks!